# NoClassDefFoundError when running APK with custom JAR

Tags: android, apk, noclassdeffounderror

It compiles just fine. Loads into my test device just fine. When I run it it crashes with a "Sorry The application Ear of Bat (process com.fleenlab.LWPA_EarOfBat) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again." on the device screen and a bunch of "failed resolving" and "link of class failed" followed by a "FATAL EXCEPTION....NoClassDefFound" in logcat.

The JAR is plain old Java that I wrote on Eclipse.

Yes, it's the same problem that so many others have had.

I tried that popular solution (http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17). I put my JAR in the libs folder. No luck.

I also tried the variant solution : referring to the JAR as an external JAR and setting the "Order and Export" check-box. Still no luck.

I even decompiled the APK (using apktool) to see if the classes were getting packaged up properly. They are.

MORE INFO
Android SDK Tools R21.0.1
Android SDK Platform-tools R16.0.1
Target API 8
Eclipse SDK Version: 3.7.2
Debian Squeeze

I'm stymied. Any clues?

(can't post images yet being a noob so here's the last bit of logcat dump in text form)

```
11-30 21:30:44.140: W/dalvikvm(926): Link of class 'Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/Bubble;' failed

11-30 21:30:44.140: W/dalvikvm(926): Unable to match class for part: 'Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/Bubble;)Ljava/util/List;'

11-30 21:30:44.140: I/dalvikvm(926): Failed resolving Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/DNode; interface 667 'Ljavax/swing/tree/TreeNode;'

11-30 21:30:44.140: W/dalvikvm(926): Link of class 'Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/DNode;' failed

11-30 21:30:44.140: I/dalvikvm(926): Failed resolving Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/Bubble; interface 678 'Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/DNode;'

11-30 21:30:44.140: W/dalvikvm(926): Link of class 'Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/Bubble;' failed

11-30 21:30:44.150: W/dalvikvm(926): Unable to match class for part: 'Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/Bubble;)Ljava/util/List;'

11-30 21:30:44.150: I/dalvikvm(926): Failed resolving Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/DNode; interface 667 'Ljavax/swing/tree/TreeNode;'

11-30 21:30:44.150: W/dalvikvm(926): Link of class 'Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/DNode;' failed

11-30 21:30:44.150: I/dalvikvm(926): Failed resolving Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/Bubble; interface 678 'Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/DNode;'

11-30 21:30:44.150: W/dalvikvm(926): Link of class 'Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/Bubble;' failed

11-30 21:30:44.150: W/dalvikvm(926): Unable to match class for part: 'Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/Bubble;)Ljava/util/List;'

11-30 21:30:44.150: I/dalvikvm(926): Failed resolving Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/DNode; interface 667 'Ljavax/swing/tree/TreeNode;'

11-30 21:30:44.150: W/dalvikvm(926): Link of class 'Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/DNode;' failed

11-30 21:30:44.150: I/dalvikvm(926): Failed resolving Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/Bubble; interface 678 'Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/DNode;'

11-30 21:30:44.150: W/dalvikvm(926): Link of class 'Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/Bubble;' failed

11-30 21:30:44.190: W/dalvikvm(926): Unable to match class for part: 'Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/Bubble;)Ljava/util/List;'

11-30 21:30:44.190: I/dalvikvm(926): Failed resolving Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/DNode; interface 667 'Ljavax/swing/tree/TreeNode;'

11-30 21:30:44.190: W/dalvikvm(926): Link of class 'Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/DNode;' failed

11-30 21:30:44.190: I/dalvikvm(926): Failed resolving Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/Bubble; interface 678 'Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/DNode;'

11-30 21:30:44.190: W/dalvikvm(926): Link of class 'Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/Bubble;' failed

11-30 21:30:44.190: W/dalvikvm(926): Unable to match class for part: 'Lorg/fleen/core/diamondGrammar/Bubble;)Ljava/util/List;'

11-30 21:30:44.240: D/dalvikvm(926): GC_CONCURRENT freed 634K, 53% free 2792K/5831K, external 716K/1038K, paused 2ms+4ms

11-30 21:30:44.560: D/dalvikvm(926): GC_CONCURRENT freed 368K, 51% free 2874K/5831K, external 716K/1038K, paused 2ms+2ms

11-30 21:30:44.660: W/dalvikvm(926): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40082560)

11-30 21:30:44.660: E/AndroidRuntime(926): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10

11-30 21:30:44.660: E/AndroidRuntime(926): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.fleen.core.diamondGrammar.Grid

11-30 21:30:44.660: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at com.fleenlab.LWPA_EarOfBat.LoopingTunnelFlowVFrameBlock_TF0000_Tight.initRootAndCore(LoopingTunnelFlowVFrameBlock_TF0000_Tight.java:90)

11-30 21:30:44.660: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at org.fleen.loopingTunnelFlowVFrameSequence.LoopingTunnelFlowVFrameBlock_Abstract.<init>(LoopingTunnelFlowVFrameBlock_Abstract.java:100)

11-30 21:30:44.660: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at com.fleenlab.LWPA_EarOfBat.LoopingTunnelFlowVFrameBlock_TF0000_Tight.<init>(LoopingTunnelFlowVFrameBlock_TF0000_Tight.java:43)

11-30 21:30:44.660: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at com.fleenlab.LWPA_EarOfBat.LoopingTunnelFlowVFrameSeq_Tight.getBlock(LoopingTunnelFlowVFrameSeq_Tight.java:17)

11-30 21:30:44.660: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at com.fleenlab.LWPA_EarOfBat.LoopingTunnelFlowVFrameSeq_Tight.<init>(LoopingTunnelFlowVFrameSeq_Tight.java:14)

11-30 21:30:44.660: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at com.fleenlab.LWPA_EarOfBat.Generator.getSeq(Generator.java:110)

11-30 21:30:44.660: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at com.fleenlab.LWPA_EarOfBat.Generator$Initializer.run(Generator.java:78)
```

Comment: Is it defined in the manifest? Also post the output in its entirety.

Comment: You mean define the Jar in the manifest? I'll try that. Here's the logcat output :

Comment: you want the WHOLE output? It's rather large. [Here's the text file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2F22cx87dREaE1SV0NOZFlKYkE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Clean all your projects and try again

Comment: That's the FIRST thing I tried. I clean them every time I think it might help. Just cleaned them again... loading the apk into the device... and nope. Still crashes.

Comment: @ Mgamerz :: I'm having no luck with <uses-library>. It keeps failing at device install with a "INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY". I'm reading elsewhere that <uses library> is only for things built in to the system image (sdk add-ons and such) and that third party shared libraries are not supported. I'm thinking that this isn't the way to go. Have you gotten any use out of <uses-library>?

Comment: I was just looking at that logcat and noticed that some of those classes not getting resolved are standard Java classes. That might be a clue.

Comment: You don't use <uses-library> to put it in the manifest. Your original question did not show you were using a library (a jar file, like the admob sdk). You need to add your library to your build path... but eclipse should have detected that. and yes, I believe INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY is because the package depends on a library that is not installed on the system. (That's why I can't take LG stuff and plop it in vanilla)

Comment: Ok, you think that INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY is there because of a missing library (and not because my JAR isn't an SDK addon or whatever, maybe). I was thinking in a similar direction. Could it be that the standard Java library JARs need to be put in there too? I'll try that. I'm using openjdk. Maybe that matters.

Comment: I haven't actually tried it yet but now that I think of it, what the linker is choking on might actually be a few special Java libraries that aren't in Android. Last time I did this I recall making a point of not using stuff like Java2D and Swing. I'll hit that later this afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

It was a dependencies thing. Grid was dependent on TreeNode, which is in Swing, which wasn't in the JAR. My solution was to get rid of TreeNode. Didn't really need it anyway. Works fine now.

I know that logcat said that the NoClassDefFound happened at Grid, but the problem wasn't actually a missing Grid class def, it was a missing def for a class to which Grid was referring.